# nodes in blender game engine

Tags: game-engine, materials, node-editor

I have an issue while tring to set up a material for blender game engine. You can see the setup on the image, and the BGE doesn't render my purple object that's on the View panel.

[image: settings]

Comment: Looks like it's an "Alpha" issue? What if you try plugging those nodes into "Color"? Can you post the blend? I just noticed how old this question is... I hope you either found your answer or find my input useful. Don't wanna get slapped for bumping something too old, if that's even an issue here.

Comment: hahaha if it is at some point they will bother you

Comment: then you'r just a purple object